# How to Convert SQL query to a Laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE ( name = '%alex%' 
    OR  address = '%alex%' 
    OR  lastname = '%alex%' 
    ) AND id = '%alex%' 
        AND email = '%alex%'
```

How I can convert above SQL query into Laravel Query builder standard?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#selects

Comment: People are probably down-voting because you don't appear to have really tried to do this yourself before asking for help. SO is not here to do your work for you, but we will help you figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('table')
        ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%alex%')
        ->orWhere('address', 'LIKE', '%alex%')
        ->orWhere('lastname', 'LIKE', '%alex%')
        ->where('id', 'LIKE', '%alex%')
        ->where('email', 'LIKE', '%alex%')
        ->get();
```